# Use onLocationChanged() updates inside a foreground service

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gps, location

I'm trying to create a foreground service that can track the user's location with the phone's GPS. I have a `ForegroundService` class, where in the `onCreate()` method I call a function that should start by asking for location updates:

```kotlin
fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

locationManager = getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

val locationListener: LocationListener = this
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 0F, locationListener
)
```

My class is implementing `Service()` and `LocationListener`. I then override `onLocationChanged`, where I should log the current speed (and leave `onAccuracyChanged` empty).

Of course I have a notification correctly showing in android, so the service is definitely running, but I seem to get no location updates anyways. What could the problem be? Thank you.

Comment: Did you request runtime permissions for location?  I don't see it there, so I'm assuming not.  You also need to request static permission in the manifest.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes, and it is checked that they have been accepted before requesting the updates. The code I’m trying to use for the foreground service was working in a normal activity, with screen on etc.

Comment: Did the user grant background location gathering permission?  In modern Android, a user can choose to allow location to be gathered when the app is foreground only.  Even if your app is foreground, running it in a Service counts as background.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes, that's done too.

Comment: does the same code you present work when ran in an Activity (in foreground)?

Comment: @JakubLicznerski This is with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69748480/use-onsensorchanged-updates-inside-a-foreground-service) question. In both cases the code that was normally working in an Activity doesn't work in a foreground service.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shared much code so I'll share a few guesses as an answer proposal:

1. **Location API selection:**

You are creating a `FusedLocationProviderClient`, but not using it. According to [this docs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates) and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33022662/android-locationmanager-vs-google-play-services) it is preferred to use this provider over `LocationManager` because of accuracy and battery usage. Try using `requestLocationUpdates` from `FusedLocationProviderClient`. Additional example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34918675/android-location-service-didnt-work-in-background).

---

2. **Listener definition:**

According to this piece of code:

```kotlin
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 0F, locationListener
)
```

you are trying to use [this overload](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener)) of [this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20android.location.LocationRequest,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20android.location.LocationListener)) which then uses a `Looper` of a thread in which it is defined. If the listener is not created within the service it may use a `Looper` which is not accessible from the service's thread.

---

**Ensure** you are calling `startForeground(id, notification)` in `onStartCommand` and that the service is staying alive ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452466/how-to-determine-if-an-android-service-is-running-in-the-foreground)).

Also check out [this repo](https://github.com/android/location-samples/tree/main/LocationUpdatesForegroundService) for an example of location services accessed within a foreground service. Read through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53510193/getting-gps-location-updates-while-app-in-the-background?rq=1) as well for additional reference.